# Is it possible to hide jid information - openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I have one room with two users.
I want that only moderator of the room knows the members-list.

Now, if the member (not moderator) sends something like this:

http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>

or

http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>

the member could know the list and the jid's of the users, I want to keep it private that information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is configurable per [room](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#roomconfig) - in most cases there is an option to show members list only to moderators.

Comment: this is not supported by openfire

Comment: Supported, of course! Check "Room is moderated", also "Role that may discover real JID" may be useful too - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ity3o1yqc6clmv/openfire.PNG